# Partial derivative in Newtons Second law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, momentum, differentiation

Newton's second law states Force is the time derivative of momentum. But is it a total derivative or partial derivative? What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, physically meaningful quantities use total derivatives. Partial derivatives are mostly mathematical tools that help us express total derivatives, since the implicit functional dependencies that even allow us to speak of a difference between partial derivatives and total ones aren't inherent features of the physical system. Rather, they depend on our choice of how we think it's most convenient to do the math. For instance, consider the function $f(t)=3t+t^2$. We can write this as a function of two variables with implicit dependencies in different ways. For instance, we could introduce the variable $u=t^2$ and express $f$ as $f(t,u)=3t+u^2$. Or we could introduce $v=3+t$ and express $f$ as $f(t,v)=tv$. The functions are really the same, but their partial derivatives are different, while their total derivatives are exactly the same. Physically meaningful things like momentum do not depend on our arbitrary choice of how to express quantities like force, so they shouldn't actually depend on partial derivatives, but total ones. Of course, total derivatives can be expressed through partial derivatives, but again, that's just math, not physics.

So in this case, since Newton's laws are physical laws, not mathematical ones, they should work with total derivatives.

Comment: What do you mean by total derivative? The gradient of the function?

Comment: @vercassivelauno there are many equations in physics which use partial derivatives for example the of heat flow.

Comment: @nasu: Depends on the context. But essentially what mathematicians mean when they say total derivative. Essentially, we have some space $M$ of "main" quantities which consists of the parameters relevant to our problem. For the mechanics of point masses, this would usually just be time. For wave or continuum mechanics, it might be spacetime. For electrostatics, it might only be the space coordinates. Whatever fits the problem we're trying to solve. **continued**

Comment: Now we want to examine some quantity $f$ which depends on multiple quantities $(Q_1,\dots,Q_n)\in\mathbb R^n$, which in turn depend on our parameters in $M$.That is, $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a function of the quantities $Q_i$, and we have a function $Q:M\to\mathbb R^n$ which describes how the quantities depend on the parameters. Then we can express $f$ in terms of the parameters mathematically via the composition $f\circ Q$. **continued**

Comment: The total derivative of $f$ as used in physics is the total derivative of the function $f\circ Q$ as used by mathematicians. This often coincides with what physicists call the gradient, especially if $M$ represents space.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous: Which is why I formulated it as a rule of thumb. But even the heat equation can be understood in the form $\frac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm dt}=\Delta u$, where $\Delta u$ is the trace of the second total derivative of $u$ as a function of space, and $\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}$ is the total derivative of $u$ as a function of time. Of course, we have to disconnect the parameter space into a spacial and a temporal part to really understand these as total derivatives, but it's still better than only seeing the partial derivatives without any interconnection between them.

Answer (score 2):

It is total derivative of momentum $p=mv$ w.r.t time: i.e. $F=d(mv)/dt=mdv/dt=ma$

Comment: Could you please explain why not partial derivative?

Comment: @I am Me : Maybe this will answer your query  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174270/855081

Comment: In order to have a partial derivative, you have to hold some independent variable(s) constant. What independent variable(s) do you think should be  held  constant?

Answer (score 2):

The $\mathbf p$ which appears in Newton's second law is a function of one variable, so the derivative which appears is just the derivative $\mathbf p'(t)$.  There is no notion of partial derivatives because there is only one variable, and there is no such thing as the "total derivative" of a function all by itself.

This is how it works:  If you have a function of one variable, then you can take its derivative in the usual way.
$$f(x) = x^2+3 \implies f'(x) = 2x$$

---

If you have a function of two variables, then you can take its derivative with respect to one of its entries while holding the other constant.
$$g(x,y)=x^2+y^3+2xy \implies \begin{cases}(\partial_1g)(x,y)=2x+2y \\(\partial_2g)(x,y) = 3y^2+2x\end{cases}$$

Here, $\partial_1g$ is the derivative of $g$ with respect to its **first slot** while holding the second one constant, and similarly for $\partial_2 g$.  These are the *partial derivatives* of $g$.  In an abuse of notation, we often understand $x$ to be the thing we plug into the first slot and $y$ the thing we plug into the second, and write $\partial_1g$ as $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$, but I'm specifically *not* doing that here.

---

Now consider what happens when you have a function of multiple variables (like $g$), but **then** we plug two different functions $a$ and $b$ of a variable (which we'll call $t$) into each of $g$'s two slots.  The result will be a composite function:

$$h(t) = g\bigg(a(t),b(t)\bigg)= [a(t)]^2 + [b(t)]^3 + 2 a(t) b(t)$$

**This** function can be differentiated with respect to $t$.  If we do so, the chain rule tells us that

$$h'(t) = a'(t) \cdot (\partial_1 g)\big(a(t),b(t)\big) + b'(t) \cdot (\partial_2g)\big(a(t),b(t)\big)$$

This is what people call the "total derivative of $g$."  My argument is that this name makes *no sense*, because it is not a property of $g$ - it is a property of $g$ *and* the two functions $a$ and $b$.

Here's a more concrete example.  The temperature in the room you're currently sitting in is a function of position $(x,y,z)$.  Pick a point - maybe the point just in front of your nose - and think about the rate of change of temperature with respect to the $x$ coordinate.  That makes sense - you can move a little bit in the $x$ direction while keeping $y$ and $z$ constant, see how the temperature changes, and calculate the derivative.  You can do the same for $y$ and $z$ to obtain the partial derivatives of the temperature with respect to position.

If I come into the room and ask you for the **total** derivative of the temperature at that point, I'd be making no sense.  What I *could* do is take a thermometer and move it past that point, and then ask you the rate of change of the temperature with respect to time.  That's well-defined, but hopefully you can see that it depends not only on the temperature field $T(x,y,z)$, but **also** on the details of how I'm moving the thermometer.

Comment: But sir, momentum can also be a function of x,y,z right?

Comment: @IamMe We’re talking about a mathematical function which takes one variable - the time - and returns the momentum of the object at that time. That is the function which appears in Newton’s second law. It is not a function of position or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Newton second law

$$\frac{d}{dt}(m\,\vec v)=m\,\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=\vec{F}\tag 1$$

the velocity $~\vec v$ is in general depending on the generalized coordinates $~\vec q~$ the velocity of the generalized coordinates $~\vec{\dot{q}}~$ and the time $~t$

$\Rightarrow$

the total derivative is

$$d\vec v=\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial \vec q}\,d\vec q+
\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial \vec{\dot{q}}}\,d\vec{\dot{q}}+\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial t}\,dt$$

Eq. (1)

$$m\,\left(\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial \vec q}\,\frac{d\vec q}{dt}+
\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial \vec{\dot{q}}}\,\frac{d\vec{\dot{q}}}{dt}+\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial t}\right)=\vec{F}$$

but if you obtain only the partial derivative , you get:

$$m\,\frac{\partial \vec v}{\partial t}=\vec{F}$$

this is    not   correct

Comment: I couldn't understand what is a generalized co-ordinate. Could you please help?

Comment: generalized coordinates are independents motions